# Search data with a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting an error with try to execute the stored procedure.

I have have a SQL Server database, the stored procedure looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Licenses_By_Number]
    @LicenseNumber int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LicenseNumber, CentralRegistryNumber, LicenseNameArabic, 
        LicenseNameEnglish, LegalForm, ExpiryDate, LicenseOwner, 
        LicenseOwnerNationality, LicenseType, LicenseActivities, 
        LicenseAddress, Phone, Fax, Email, LicenseStatus 
    FROM
        LicensesTbl 
    WHERE 
        LicenseNumber = @LicenseNumber
END
```

In Vb I have data layer and code like so:

```
  Friend Function Search_Licenses_By_Number(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByRef dr As SqlDataReader, ByVal LicenseNumber As Integer)
            Dim retval As Integer
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Search_Licenses_By_Number")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber, SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CentralRegistryNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseNameArabic", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseNameEnglish", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LegalForm", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpiryDate", SqlDbType.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseOwnerNationality", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseActivities", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

            retval = dm.executeReader(cmd, dr)

            Return retval
        End Function
```

And also I have a business layer and code like so:

```
 Public Function Search_Licenses_By_Number(ByVal LicenseNumber As Integer) As Integer
            p.Search_Licenses_By_Number(cmd, dr, LicenseNumber)
            Return p.Search_Licenses_By_Number(cmd, dr, LicenseNumber)
        End Function
```

I have form that contains 14 textboxes and 1 datetime picker and 1 button

What I want to is when press search button it display the record in textboxes depend on LicenseNumber that entered in textbox1

The button code like so :

```
Dim retval As Integer = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number(txtLicensesNumber.Text)
        txtLicensesNumber.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseNumber")
        CentralRegistryNumber.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("CentralRegistryNumber")
        txtLicensesNameArabic.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseNameArabic")
        txtLicensesNameEnglish.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseNameEnglish")
        LegalForm.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LegalForm")
        ExpiryDate.Value = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("ExpiryDate").ToString
        LicenseOwner.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseOwner")
        LicenseOwnerNationality.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseOwnerNationality")
        txtLicensesType.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseType")
        LicenseActivities.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseActivities")
        txtLicensesAddress.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseAddress")
        LicensePhone.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("Phone")
        LicenseFax.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("Fax")
        LicenseEmail.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("Email")
        LicStatus.Text = p.Search_Licenses_By_Number("LicenseStatus")
```

The error I am getting is

> Procedure Search_Licenses_By_Number has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Kind Regards
Salem

Answer (score 0):

The procedure in the database has only one parameter defined and you are providing 15 parameters.
Define all parameters in SP as below

```
 USE [MPRS]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Search_Licenses_By_Number]    Script Date: 26-Nov-16 8:06:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Licenses_By_Number]
@LicenseNumber int,
 @CentralRegistryNumber int,
         @LicenseNameArabic nvarchar(max), 
        @LicenseNameEnglish nvarchar(max), 
        @LegalForm nvarchar(max),
        @ExpiryDate datetime,
        @LicenseOwner nvarchar(max),
        @LicenseOwnerNationality nvarchar(max),
        @LicenseType nvarchar(max),
        @LicenseActivities nvarchar(max),
        @LicenseAddress nvarchar(max),
        @Phone nvarchar(max), 
        @Fax nvarchar(max), 
        @Email nvarchar(max), 
        @LicenseStatus nvarchar(max),
as

begin

Select LicenseNumber,CentralRegistryNumber, LicenseNameArabic, `LicenseNameEnglish, LegalForm, ExpiryDate, LicenseOwner, LicenseOwnerNationality, LicenseType, LicenseActivities, LicenseAddress, Phone, Fax, Em`ail, LicenseStatus from LicensesTbl 
Where LicenseNumber = @LicenseNumber
End
```

Comment: Thank You But i got another error  Procedure or function 'Search_Licenses_By_Number' expects parameter '@CentralRegistryNumber', which was not supplied.  i want to put LicenseNumber in textbox and it return to me all data i want  CentralRegistryNumber, LicenseNameArabic, `LicenseNameEnglish, LegalForm, ExpiryDate, LicenseOwner, LicenseOwnerNationality, LicenseType, LicenseActivities, LicenseAddress, Phone, Fax, Em`ail, LicenseStatus

Comment: a semicolon is missing between first and second parameter. check updated code

Comment: any other suggestions

Comment: Is same error still exists, or the error has changed?

Comment: NOW iam getting  Procedure or function 'Search_Licenses_By_Number' expects parameter '@CentralRegistryNumber', which was not supplied.

Comment: check the call, if you are providing the values for all paramters?

Comment: If not then set default value for parameter like https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: even i set default value iam getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CentralRegistryNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseNameArabic", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseNameEnglish", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LegalForm", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpiryDate", SqlDbType.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseOwnerNationality", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseActivities", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicenseStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using just select as this can return multiple rows,
Always go for "Distinct Select" while returning row/rows as result set.
Try using table valued function call.
or do it like this as shown below

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[Search_Licenses_By_Number]", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>();
Test test;

while (reader.Read())
{
    test = new Test();
    test.LicenseNumber = int.Parse(reader["LicenseNumber"].ToString());

test.CentralRegistryNumber = int.Parse(reader["CentralRegistryNumber"].ToString());
test.LicenseNameArabic = int.Parse(reader["LicenseNameArabic"].ToString());
 test.LicenseNameEnglish = int.Parse(reader["LicenseNameEnglish"].ToString());
 test.LegalForm = int.Parse(reader["LegalForm"].ToString());
 test.ExpiryDate = int.Parse(reader["ExpiryDate "].ToString());
 test.LicenseOwner= int.Parse(reader["LicenseOwner"].ToString());
 test.LicenseOwnerNationality= int.Parse(reader["LicenseOwnerNationality"].ToString());
 test.LicenseType= int.Parse(reader["LicenseType"].ToString());
 test.LicenseActivities= int.Parse(reader["LicenseActivities"].ToString());
 test.LicenseAddress= int.Parse(reader["LicenseAddress"].ToString());
 test.Phone= int.Parse(reader["Phone"].ToString());
 test.Fax= int.Parse(reader["Fax"].ToString());
 test.Email= int.Parse(reader["Email"].ToString());
 test.LicenseStatus= int.Parse(reader["LicenseStatus"].ToString());

    TestList.Add(test);
}
//sampling it in grid, you may use this data list as per your requirement
gvGrid.DataSource = TestList;
gvGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank You Sir iam not using c# :(